# Readers-Writers problem - issues with the fairness for both readers and writers

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, conditional-statements, locking

I was given a task to write a Readers-Writers program in java, in this case with fairness to both of the readers and writers in Java. For the first two runs the program worked, however when I ran it with 30 readers and 3 writers it stopped working. I'm not sure what could be the reason for that... I create two lists of `ReaderThread` and `WriterThread` objects and start them in a main method (not included here) and then use `join()` through both the list so the threads are created without errors. The code so far:

```
public class ReaderWriter {
    static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    static Lock queue = new ReentrantLock();
       static Condition read  = lock.newCondition(); 
       static Condition write = lock.newCondition(); 
    static AtomicInteger readWait = new AtomicInteger(0);
    static AtomicInteger readActive = new AtomicInteger(0);
    static AtomicInteger writeWait= new AtomicInteger(0);
    static AtomicInteger writeActive = new AtomicInteger(0);
    static StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    static int val = 0;
    static class ReaderThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                queue.lock();
                lock.lock();
                
                while (writeWait.get() > 0 ) 
                    read.await();
                readWait.getAndIncrement();
                read.signal();
                queue.unlock();
                lock.unlock();
                
                System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " is reading a string: " + str);
                Thread.sleep(1500);
                System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " has stopped reading");
                lock.lock();
                readWait.getAndDecrement();
                if (readWait.getAndDecrement() ==  0 ) {
                    write.signal();
                } 
                
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    static class WriterThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                queue.lock();
                lock.lock();
                
                while(readWait.get() > 0 ||  writeWait.get() > 0)   
                    write.await();
                writeWait.getAndIncrement();
                
                queue.unlock();
                lock.unlock();
                
                System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " is writing");
                str.append(val);
                val++;
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " has stopped writing");
                lock.lock();
                writeWait.getAndDecrement();
            
                    if(writeWait.get() == 0) {
                        read.signal();
                    } else {
                        write.signal();
                    }
            
                lock.unlock();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output I get from running the program with 20 readers and 2 writers looks like this, and it freezes there:

```
Thread: 13 is writing
Thread: 13 has stopped writing
Thread: 14 is reading a string: 0
Thread: 16 is reading a string: 0
Thread: 14 has stopped reading
Thread: 16 has stopped reading
```

However, sometimes the prgram just works and the output is as follows (20 readers and 2 writers aswell):

```
Thread: 13 is writing
Thread: 13 has stopped writing
Thread: 14 is reading a string: 0
Thread: 14 has stopped reading
Thread: 12 is writing
Thread: 12 has stopped writing
Thread: 16 is reading a string: 01
Thread: 18 is reading a string: 01
Thread: 17 is reading a string: 01
Thread: 15 is reading a string: 01
Thread: 20 is reading a string: 01
Thread: 21 is reading a string: 01
Thread: 19 is reading a string: 01
Thread: 23 is reading a string: 01
Thread: 22 is reading a string: 01
Thread: 25 is reading a string: 01
Thread: 26 is reading a string: 01
Thread: 27 is reading a string: 01
Thread: 24 is reading a string: 01
Thread: 30 is reading a string: 01
Thread: 31 is reading a string: 01
Thread: 29 is reading a string: 01
Thread: 28 is reading a string: 01
Thread: 33 is reading a string: 01
Thread: 32 is reading a string: 01
Thread: 28 has stopped reading
Thread: 29 has stopped reading
Thread: 18 has stopped reading
Thread: 17 has stopped reading
Thread: 21 has stopped reading
Thread: 19 has stopped reading
Thread: 23 has stopped reading
Thread: 24 has stopped reading
Thread: 27 has stopped reading
Thread: 33 has stopped reading
Thread: 26 has stopped reading
Thread: 32 has stopped reading
Thread: 16 has stopped reading
Thread: 22 has stopped reading
Thread: 25 has stopped reading
Thread: 20 has stopped reading
Thread: 15 has stopped reading
Thread: 30 has stopped reading
Thread: 31 has stopped reading
```

But more often than not the program just does not reach the end of it. I'm not really sure where this might come from, any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

On Linux by any chance? Something similar involving Threads whose work is neither completed nor have the Threads exited. With CPU_NUMBER of Threads processing internal arrays (no /IO, no synchronization, no deadlock), things start off well, then 3 Threads starve the others of CPU, then 2 dominate and when they are finished it's like the program just forgot about the others. I can see on System Monitor that everything is quiescent.

** update**
made my  UncaughtExceptionHandler print something to output and voila there are the missing Threads. Program didn't stop because missing threads didn't count down an int value Thread.main checks before exiting. Assign an UncaughtExceptionHandler to your Thread and spit something out; maybe it will be informative.

Programmer error, thank goodness. Hope you have the same luck !

**update 2** exception caused by OutOfMemoryError / heap space.